# Setting Java environmental variables on Centos 7 breaks the $PATH

Tags: java, linux, centos7

After installing Java 8 on a Centos 7 server I added the following lines to /etc/environment

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_161
export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_161/jre
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_161/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/bin
```

However after a restart on the box, after I login it comes up with

```
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: id: command not found
/usr/libexec/grepconf.sh: line 5: grep: command not found
```

This makes me think I have broken the PATH variable somehow, but I cannot open /etc/environment as "less", "vi" and etc are not recognised as commands.

And ideas on that I did wrong and how do I fix the current state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't `export` in `/etc/environment`. Instead, provide only the definitions, such as `JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_161`.

Use the full path to `vi`, such as `/usr/bin/vi` to fix the file. This way `PATH` (which is exported in the now failing `/etc/environment`) won't be searched.

Here is an example command.

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/vi /etc/environment
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, the paths to the commands did work, however even with the new state of /etc/environment the path variable is still broken:

Comment: JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_161
JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_161/jre
PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_161/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/bin

Comment: Have you exited/reloaded the shell?

Comment: Yes, i restarted the whole box - once with an empty file - which worked, then with this, which does not work

Comment: Instead of `PATH=$PATH:/bla`, try appending your `/opt/java/bla` paths to the existing `PATH` in `/etc/environment`

Comment: There isn't such - when I first opened the file - it was empty. What I have posted here are all of its contents.

Comment: My `/etc/environment` has `PATH` in it.
`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"`

Comment: So, I had a look at the path that I have with empty env file and it look similar to yours, but when I modify it through env, the initial values seem to disappear, so I added them as well and everything seems to be working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked.
I was just reading about CentOS environment, and it looks like ideally you should create an `/etc/profile.d` script, such as `/etc/profile.d/java.sh`, and set your environment variable and path in there, which wouldn't mess up your path like setting them in `/etc/environment` did.